# Julia: Struct with constant field to optimize performance

Tags: performance, struct, julia

`foo` is a callable example struct that will have additional fields later. Since some of these fields hold arrays with changing values it's not an option to make the instance a `const G`. However, the boolean value `b` stays constant. Is there a way to tell the compiler that this field will never change in order to enable optimizations? In this example I would like `F` to be as fast as `G` and `H`.

```
using BenchmarkTools

struct foo
  b::Bool
end

function (f::foo)(x)
  if f.b
    x+1
  end
end

F = foo(true)

const G = foo(true)

H(x) = x+1


@btime F(1) # 12.078 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

@btime G(1) # 0.023 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

@btime H(1) # 0.024 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Comment: "Since some of these fields hold arrays with changing values it's not an option to make the instance a const G" -- this sounds like a misunderstanding. An instance of a directly or indirectly mutable struct can well be `const`. `const` in Julia does not work like in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not benchmarking the `F` correctly. Here is a way to do it:

```
julia> @btime $F(1)
  0.026 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
2
```

The problem is not that `F` is a global non-constant variable while `G` is a constant, so when accessing `F` its value is not stable within `@btime`.

Adding a `$` in front of the call makes `F` a local variable during a benchmark and you can then see that it is equally fast.

Also it is probably better to benchmark some larger functions in such cases. Here is a quick example:

```
julia> function test(x)
       s = 0
       for i in 1:10^6
           s += x(1)
       end
       s
       end
test (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @btime test($F)
  35.830 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
2000000

julia> @btime test($G)
  35.839 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
2000000
```

Also you can check with `@code_native` that `F` and `G` end up with identical native code:

```
julia> @code_native F(1)
    .text
; ┌ @ REPL[10]:2 within `foo'
    cmpb    $0, (%rsi)
    je  L17
; │ @ REPL[10]:3 within `foo'
; │┌ @ int.jl:53 within `+'
    addq    $1, %rdx
; │└
    movq    %rdx, (%rdi)
    movb    $2, %dl
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    retq
L17:
    movb    $1, %dl
    xorl    %eax, %eax
; │ @ REPL[10]:3 within `foo'
    retq
    nopw    %cs:(%rax,%rax)
; └

julia> @code_native G(1)
    .text
; ┌ @ REPL[10]:2 within `foo'
    cmpb    $0, (%rsi)
    je  L17
; │ @ REPL[10]:3 within `foo'
; │┌ @ int.jl:53 within `+'
    addq    $1, %rdx
; │└
    movq    %rdx, (%rdi)
    movb    $2, %dl
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    retq
L17:
    movb    $1, %dl
    xorl    %eax, %eax
; │ @ REPL[10]:3 within `foo'
    retq
    nopw    %cs:(%rax,%rax)
; └
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Now I am wondering though why `H` is fast from the start, without putting the "$", since I am not explicitly declaring it constant.

Comment: You are, `H(x) = x+1` defines a function with a name `H`, while, `F = foo(true)` binds `foo(true)` value to a variable `F`. You can check that you are not able to rebind `H` to an arbitrary value by writing `H = 10` (you get an error), while writing `F = 10` adds a new binding to a variable `F`. Is this clear now?